# What is the right way of replacing a part of line in a file

Tags: c++, fstream, seek

I have a file `GENERIC_MAC` with some configurations for my machine, and I want to replace the MAC to a given MAC (hard-coded in this case).

Is this the right way? (*The code gets me the desired output but I'm not sure about the `fs.tellp();` + `fs.seekp(position);`* )

***I have made the assumption (I think its reasonable) that a MAC address has is always of the same length (e.g. `"XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB:CC"`)***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* path = "....GENERIC_MAC";
    char* MAC  = "XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB:CC"; /* the actual code returns the MAC as char* - should I convert to string? */
    string prefix = "this is my MAC - ";
    size_t pos;
    fstream fs(path);
    string line;
    streampos position;

    cout << "START\n";

    while (std::getline(fs, line))      {
        if ((pos = line.find(prefix, 0)) == std::string::npos) {
            position = fs.tellp();
            continue;
        }
        /* replace the 00:11:22:33:44:55 MAC with this device's MAC */
        cout << "old = " << line << endl;
        line.replace(pos + prefix.length(), string::npos, MAC);
        cout << "new = " << line << endl;

        fs.seekp(position);
        fs << line << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << "END\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

The file looks something like this:

```
router interface
         address 10.10.10.10/24 

blah
         this is my MAC - XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB:CC

...
...
...
```

Comment: Seems right. I don't see another way of moving around a file. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream)

Comment: As long as the replacement text is exactly the same size as the text it is replacing.

Comment: The only part that troubles me is the replace. You uncondionally replace the end of the line with the new MAC address, without even controlling the line length. You should at least control that what remains has the expected length. Or if you want to accept extra (possibly blank) characters at the end, control that it has at least the expected length and only replace the length of the new MAC address. Posted as a comment because it does not address the main part of your question.